# Download SSL certificate from website and send it

Tags: android, ssl, certificate

We are developing a security conscious application and we need are application to send us the certificate that was used for connection.

Is it possible to download the certificate and send it on Android. We need to do this so that we can check to see if the certificate has been compromised. Or would be better to retreive details from the certificate write it to a log and then send it. We have an api that can send the details

Answer (score 1):

I see you have asked for pinning previously...

You can pin the certificate in the following way

```
Certificate[] certs = conn.getServerCertificates();
MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
for (Certificate cert : certs) {
    X509Certificate x509Certificate = (X509Certificate) cert;
    byte[] key = x509Certificate.getPublicKey().getEncoded();
    md.update(key, 0, key.length);
    byte[] hashBytes = md.digest();
    StringBuilder hexHash = new StringBuilder();
    for (byte hashByte : hashBytes) {
        int k = 0xFF & hashByte;
        String tmp = (k < 16) ? "0" : "";
        tmp += Integer.toHexString(0xFF & hashByte);
        hexHash.append(tmp);
    }
    // You can even log cert.toString()
    Log.d(TAG, hexHash.toString()); get the hash from here
    // If you create `pins` as a Set with all the valid pins from above
    if (pins.contains(hexHash.toString())) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

You can run this after the connection `conn` has been connected then if the pin does not match you can abort before sending data. Note: the above code pins the public key of the certificate not the certificate.

If you just want the certificate you can just get `cert.toString()`

Comment: When I try and run `URL url = new URL(PATH);` `HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();` and `connection.connect();` I get a `javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found` when using a proxy on my android device (mitmproxy and fiddler) but not when not using a proxy

Comment: I guess you are using a M+ device, in that case you need to add your proxies SSL certificate to the network security config.

Comment: I am running this on Android 6.0 and 7.0. I don't know how configure the network security config. It seems to work in android 6.0.